# How to format action link pass parameter in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.actionlink, url.action

I have a trouble with action link as text in mvc .

```
  function ListProduct() {
            $.get('@Url.Action("ListProduct", "Product")')
                 .done(function (data) {
                     var json = JSON.parse(data.result);
                     $.each(json, function (idx, obj) {
                        $("#tb_product tbody").append(
                        '<tr>' +
                        ' <td>' + obj.CATEGORY_NAME + '</td>' +
                        ' <td><a href="@Url.Action("Detail", "Product", new { id = '+ obj.PRODUCT_ID + ' })">' + obj.PRODUCT_NAME + '</a></td>' +' </tr>');
                        });
                    });
        }
```

But seem it's not working, it's get error `too many charaters in character literal`   at `'+ obj.PRODUCT_ID + '` .
Thank you see it.

Comment: Please enclose more of your server side code (the code around, above and below) this code, so we can see the context of this line of code. We are assuming that your mvc code block is defined correctly but we need to check that.

Comment: Yes, I update my code snippet, in this case, `CATEGORY_NAME` and `PRODUCT_NAME` is show , the problem in here , format action link in view razor mvc4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Razor code (`@Url.Action(...)`) runs *server-side*, while JavaScript runs client-side, long after the server has already done it's work, returned a response, and moved on to other things. As a result, you can't pass a JavaScript variable into a Razor method, as that JavaScript variable doesn't even exist as a thing yet.

If you need to include the value as part of the actual URL path, then you can perhaps construct the path manually. For example:

```
'<a href="@Url.Action("Detail", "Product")'+ obj.PRODUCT_ID + '">' + obj.PRODUCT_NAME + '</a>'
```

In other words, server-side, `@Url.Action("Detail", "Product")` is evaluated an returns something like `/product/detail/`. Then, client-side, in your JavaScript, all you're doing is just concatenating the product id onto this existing string, resulting in something like `/product/detail/xxxxxx`.

Comment: His razor code isn't even running. That call to `@Url.Action` is getting passed straight down to the client as is. I have asked him for his controller and full view code. I'm not sure he knows what that is or if that exists. I think he's treating it like just another js file.

Comment: Well, as @Chris Pratt say, in client-side, I want return link as `/product/detail/xxxx` ,  That's why I need the javascript format url.action . I think it is like  `'<td><a href="@Url.Action("Detail", "Product")/' + obj.PRODUCT_ID + '">' + obj.PRODUCT_NAME + '</a></td>' +`   with slash  `/`   in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just "level confusion" about what's generated by mvc and what is generated by javascript. Mvc doesn't use string concatenation to construct it's  helper method calls. In this case it uses the open and close parenthesis of `@Url.Action` to parse out the method call from the surrounding text. Sticking string concatenation in the middle of that makes the mvc code parse fail.

The error your getting is from mvc as it tries to process the `@Url.Action` and fails because it's not expecting string concatenation in the middle of a call it.

In my fix here, see that

```
@Url.Action("Detail", "Product", new { id = obj.PRODUCT_ID })
```

is pure c# code. It's purely and only processed by the server, not by javascript.

I don't know how your serving this code, but you can't just serve a javascript file from an mvc project and expect it to work. It has to be served from a controller method that returns a view. That view can contain this code. But if your client side page references this by script url and it just downloads it, mvc server methods won't work even if the script is on the same web site as all the controller stuff.

```js
    $("#tb_product tbody").append(
      "<tr>" +
      " <td><a href='@Url.Action("Detail", "Product", new { id = obj.PRODUCT_ID })'> @obj.PRODUCT_NAME </a></td>" +
      " </tr>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i try same as you say , but it's not working, please check it clearly.Thank you.

Comment: Error `The name 'obj' does not exist in the current context` at line `"<td><a href='@Url.Action("Detail", "Product", new { id = obj.PRODUCT_ID })'> @obj.PRODUCT_NAME </a></td>" +`
`

Comment: @BrianCrist, ok so that means that `@Url.Action` is not getting processed as an mvc helper method. The whole thing is getting passed down to javascript to process. So we need to find out why `@Url.Action` is not getting processed as a server method. Why doens't your view template recognize the call to `@Url.Action`? That's the question now. My syntax inside `@Url.Action`, I'm pretty confident that's correct.

Comment: yes, before your answer, i see `@{`   and `}` , then you removed them, Although I've tried your way, but I can not show it . Everything still showing good form, only error at line `"<td><a href='@Url.Action("Detail", "Product", new { id = obj.PRODUCT_ID })'> @obj.PRODUCT_NAME </a></td>" +` .

Comment: @BrianCrist, that was a mistake on my part. `@{` and `}` are to set off server side code blocks, not javascript code blocks.

Comment: if you say it is not possible according to implement this at the client with javascript . @@ . and  I leave the answer above is not true in this case @!@